# How can I check if a value can be cast to a generic type?

Tags: c#, generics, types, casting, nullable

I have a method wrapping some external API call which often returns `null`. When it does, I want to return a `default` value. The method looks like this

```
public static T GetValue<T>(int input)
{
    object value = ExternalGetValue(input);
    return value != null ? (T)value : default(T)
}
```

The problem is that `(T)value` might throw an invalid cast exception. So I thought I would change it to

```
    var value = ExternalGetValue(input) as Nullable<T>;
```

but this requires `where T : struct`, and I want to allow reference types as well.

Then I tried adding an overload which would handle both.

```
public static T GetValue<T>(int input) where T : struct { ... }
public static T GetValue<T>(int input) where T : class { ... }
```

but I found you can't overload based on constraints.

I realize I can have two methods with different names, one for nullable types and one for nonnullable types, but I'd rather not do that.

Is there a good way to check if I can cast to `T` without using `as`? Or can I use `as` and have a single method which works for all types?

Comment: If the method returns a different type than you expected, it's probably a good thing that an exception is thrown. Are you sure you're not trying to hide an error, instead of solving it?

Comment: @svick This is a good point. More specifically, this is getting user inputted data that *should* be a specific type, but might not be. I guess it would be better to let the user know there was an error rather than giving them a default value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `is`:

```
return value is T ? (T)value : default(T);
```

(Note that `value is T` will return `false` if `value` is null.)